# Unable to get proper table key from nginx lua?

Tags: json, nginx, post, lua

Currently posting this data:

`{"test":"hello","test2":"world"}`

Header is this:

`"Content-Type: application/json"`

Currently trying to loop through the json but in my code, it already treats the posted data as `table` for some reason. So its useless even when I tried to encode & decode the json to table.

Anyways, when I loop through it, I'm getting only one loop where the key is like this:

```
"test":"hello"
```

I'm wondering what went wrong here. I'm trying to loop through each key & set the value to redis.

They key is supposed to be like this:

`test`

Here is my `content_by_lua` part:

```
content_by_lua '
             local cjson = require "cjson"
             local redis = require "resty.redis"
             local red = redis:new()
             red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec

             local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
             if not ok then
                ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                return
             end


             ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
             ngx.req.read_body()

             local data, err = ngx.req.get_post_args()
             if not data then
               ngx.say("err: ",err)
               return
             end

             ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_OK

             for key, val in pairs(data) do
                   ok, err = red:set(key, val)
                   if not ok then
                     ngx.say("failed to set key: ", err)
                     return
                   end
             end
           ';
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If the code is expecting a a Lua table to iterate through, then it will not handle the JSON-formatted string that you are testing with:

`{"test":"hello","test2":"world"}`

As a Lua table, it should be:

`{"test" = "hello", "test2" = "world"}`

Now, why it is not properly decoding the JSON, etc. that I cannot tell from the code you have posted.