# Unable to decode json in nginx lua?

Tags: json, curl, nginx, post, lua

Currently posting this data via `curl`:

`{"test2":"hello","test3":"world"}`

My POST is like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '{"test2":"hello","test3":"world"}'   http://localhost/test
```

Here is a part of my request:

```
    ngx.req.read_body()
    local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                 if not data then
                   ngx.say("err: ",err)
                   return
                 end

                 ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_OK

                 local eJson = cjson.encode(data)

                 local dJson = cjson.decode(eJson) -- decode json to lua table
                 ngx.say("Encoded: "..eJson);
                 ngx.say("Decoded: "..dJson);
```

Encoded & Decoded Json output:

`Encoded: "{\"test2\":\"hello\",\"test3\":\"world\"}"
Decoded: {"test2":"hello","test3":"world"}`

I believe its supposed to be something like this:

```
{"test" = "hello", "test2" = "world"}
```

How come I'm getting a different output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get proper table key from nginx lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150465/unable-to-get-proper-table-key-from-nginx-lua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, it seems like I had to decode one more time.

```
local dJson = cjson.decode(eJson) 
-- first decode (made it from stringified JSON into a JSON)

local d2Json = cjson.decode(dJson) 
-- second decode (made it from JSON into a table)
```

Hope this helps anyone out there.